# Internet Explorer 11: table.rows not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-table, internet-explorer-11, tablerow

I have this jasmine test suits working properly on Google Chrome/ Firefox (and which used to work with Internet Explorer):

http://gem-calendar.com/shared_code/test/js_test/control_utilities_test.html

After adding a new test today, I realized that the following code lines (571 in Dreamweaver) are no longer working with Internet Explorer 11:

```
var table = document.getElementById('LOG_TABLE');

var length = table.rows[0].cells.length;
```

[image: Error javascript : Unable to get property 'cells' of undefined or null reference]

When I print the table variable with `console.log()`, I can see that IE is able to fetch the table, but not to find the rows within the table.

[image: Developer tools IE 11]

but, everything is fine with chrome:

[image: Developer tools Google Chrome]

and firefox:

[image: Developer tools Firefox]

I'm quite puzzled here since `table.rows` is a pretty standard function in javascript and it doesn't seem to have similar issues reported elsewhere.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: try clearing cache

Comment: I cleared everything, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Sanchit Patiyal If you're interested to know, it seems that Internet Explorer 11 doesn't like that we set CSS rules such as `display: block;` and `display: table;` for the `<table>`

Comment: ohhh that's strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow guys, believe it or not, it was the CSS file which was causing the problem.

```
table.TABLE_V_SCROLL>tbody, div.TABLE_V_SCROLL>div.tbody {

    display: block;
}
```

and

```
table.TABLE_V_SCROLL>thead, div.TABLE_V_SCROLL>div.thead {

    display: table;
}
```

It seems that internet explorer 11 doesn't appreciate that we set the display property for tables.

The problem now is that those lines are required for my code to work on Google Chrome -_-...